# Running an android app with appium and listen to all user (real) click?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

I want to launch an app with appium and run some script that are listening for all the user click (real click in app). For example In selenium web test we could execute a Js script to do that.

The objective is to get the element id or xpath without using appium-inspector.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: Hi, could you try this https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/  OR appium-inspector has recording option

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's possible to do, but here is the steps how to do it in inspector:

1. Intall application on device (`adb install appName.apk`)
2. open Appium App and launch server
3. in Appium click on "Start inspector session"
   [image]
4. You'll need to add application info (make sure you are using correct appPackage and appActivity)

[image]

5. After entering data press "Start Session"
6. And now press Record and you can interact with elements using Appium inspector:
   [image]